# Email to distribution list not delivered via SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

I was trying to send email via SFMC to distribution list, the email delivers to the single email address where as i am not receiving email via distribution list, is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the distribution list email address is one that Marketing Cloud would never send to, such as "help@"; "info@"; 'admin@"